# ngSubmit not working (Following Traversy Media Angular Crash Course)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My ngSubmit is not working. The problem is that I am trying to follow [Angular Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dHNOWTI7H8) this tutorial at 1:30:00 mark he tries to add in onSubmit alert and I don't get the alert, because onSubmit is not getting called so I am assuming [(ngSubmit)] is the problem. Also in add-task.component.ts I can't access this.day and this.reminder for somereason

The tutorial is outdated, it is using angular 11 and the one I downloaded angular 13 so I have to add in extra ? and ! for some reason.

Here is the HTML

add-task.component.html

```
<form  class="add-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="text">Task</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="text"
        [(ngModel)]="text"
        id="text"
        placeholder="Add Task"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="day">Day & Time</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="day"
        [(ngModel)]="day"
        id="day"
        placeholder="Add Day & Time"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control form-control-check">
      <label for="reminder">Set Reminder</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="reminder"
        [(ngModel)]="reminder"
        id="reminder"
      />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Task" class="btn btn-block" />
  </form>
```

add-task.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from 'src/Task';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-task',
  templateUrl: './add-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-task.component.css']
})
export class AddTaskComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() onAddTask: EventEmitter<Task> = new EventEmitter();
  text?: string;
  day?: string;
  reminder: boolean = false;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.text) {
      alert('Please add a task!');
      return;
    }

    const newTask: Task = {
      text: this.text,
      day: this.day,
      reminder: this.reminder,
    };

    this.onAddTask.emit(newTask);

    this.text = '';
    this.day = '';
    this.reminder = false;
  }
}
```

I read some previous questions and they all say that you also have to add type submit in your button and my button is type submit so I am not sure.

I am not getting alert in onSubmit() and I can't access this.day

[image]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lzpxsh works fine here

Comment: I guess pressing the wrong button

Comment: Provide a default value to `day` and `text` like this `day: string = ''` and `text: string = ''`. Then you will be able to remove `?` from the fields. This will fix the error in console

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar problem - couldn't spy for the call of onSubmit(), when clicking the submit button. The solution was:

Rename your "onSubmit()" function to something else like "submit()".
Angular Forms [use a function with this name internally](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#onsubmit)
and this causes trouble.